# Delete files generated during session after/during session is destroyed

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

In my project,text files and audio files are generated for each client and saved on server. I want them to be deleted after everytime their session is destroyed.
There is no logout button so the session is destroyed only when browser closes.
Hypothetical solution is to overload session_destroy() to execute unlink command for the files.But i dont have a practical solution. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: server cannot (reliably) detect when the browser is closed anyways. you'd have to override the php session garbage collector and run cleanups as you find/trash expired session files.

Comment: Make a session management and timeout with mysql and create a cron consulting expired sessions.